# How to divide arc, line, and angle with a certain ratio?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

A simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent,pstricks,pst-eucl} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
\pstCircleABC[PosAngle=60]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of compiling:

[image]

**Question 1:**

How to get a point M such as MA=2/3AB, or more generally MA=(a/b)AB and a point M' belong to small arc CA such as arc M'A=2/3AB, or more generally  M'A=(a/b)AB.

**Question 2:**

How to get bisector of angle A BUT are two bisectors or three bisectors.

*Responding to AS'comment below.*

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your second question more clearly please?  what do you mean by "BUT are ..."

Comment: @Thruston In pst-eucl documentation, only to  draw one bisector, " BUT are " is equivalent " to get". My English is not so good. :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Step 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-3)(7,5)
\pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
\pstCircleABC[PosAngle=60]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\pstHomO[HomCoef=0.6666]{A}{B}[M]% 2/3 --> 0.6666
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: `HomCoef` cannot accept RPN `2 3 div` so I have to insert `0.6666` (3 decimals places should suffice, I think).

[image]

## Step 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-3)(7,5)
\pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
\pstCircleABC[PosAngle=60]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\pstHomO[HomCoef=0.6666]{A}{B}[M]% 2/3 --> 0.6666
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.3333,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{C}{O}{A}]{O}{C}[M']
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: `AngleCoef` must come before `RotAngle`. It is not commutative!

[image]

## Step 3 (Final)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-3)(7,5)
\pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
\pstCircleABC[PosAngle=225]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\pstHomO[HomCoef=0.6666]{A}{B}[M]% 2/3 --> 0.6666
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.3333,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{C}{O}{A}]{O}{C}[M']
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.3333,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[P1]
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.6666,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[P2]
\pstInterLL{B}{C}{A}{P1}{Q1}
\pstInterLL{B}{C}{A}{P2}{Q2}
\psset{Mark=MarkHash,MarkAngle=90,MarkAngleRadius=.8}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{Q1}{}
\pstMarkAngle{Q1}{A}{Q2}{}
\pstMarkAngle{Q2}{A}{C}{}
\psset{linestyle=dashed}
\psline(A)(Q1)
\psline(A)(Q2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: We have `\pstSegmentMark` (ends with `Mark`) to mark a segment but we have `\pstMarkAngle` (begins with `Mark`) to mark an angle. It seems the package author likes making inconsistent names.

[image]

## Last Edit

`\pscalculate` from `pst-calculate`  package can make me possible to insert infix calculations fed to the `HomCoef` and `AngleCoef`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 
\usepackage{pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-3)(7,5)
\pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
\pstCircleABC[PosAngle=225]{A}{B}{C}{O}
\pstHomO[HomCoef=\pscalculate{2/3}]{A}{B}[M]% Now without hard coded 0.6666
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=\pscalculate{1/3},RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{C}{O}{A}]{O}{C}[M']
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=\pscalculate{1/3},RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[P1]
\pstRotation[AngleCoef=\pscalculate{2/3},RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[P2]
\pstInterLL{B}{C}{A}{P1}{Q1}
\pstInterLL{B}{C}{A}{P2}{Q2}
\psset{Mark=MarkHash,MarkAngle=90,MarkAngleRadius=.8}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{Q1}{}
\pstMarkAngle{Q1}{A}{Q2}{}
\pstMarkAngle{Q2}{A}{C}{}
\psset{linestyle=dashed}
\psline(A)(Q1)
\psline(A)(Q2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good. This is a exciting trick.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-3)(7,5)
  \pstTriangle(2,4){A}(0,0){B}(6,0){C}
  \pstCircleABC[PosAngle=60]{A}{B}{C}{O}
  \pstHomO[HomCoef=0.667]{A}{B}[M]
  \pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.333,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{C}{O}{A}]{O}{C}[M']
  \psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
  \pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.333,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[M1]
  \pstRotation[AngleCoef=0.667,RotAngle=\pstAngleAOB{B}{A}{C}]{A}{B}[M2]
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed](A)(M1)
  \pcline[linestyle=dashed](A)(M2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mr. Herbert, could you modify the `HomCoef` and `AngleCoef` to be able to accept postfix notation? Defining a new command named `\pstAngleMark` as an alias of `\pstMarkAngle`. Modifying the core such that  `AngleCoef` and `RotAngle` can be interchanged. Thank you!

Comment: I found a "bug" in `\psCircleTangents`. See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464145/87876). Try change `\x` from `3` to `5` with step 1. The tangent line moves from one side to opposite side when the radii change from smaller to equal.